# Is there any difference between 见到 and 见着?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Person 1 says: 我不想再见到你

Person 2 says: 谁想再见着你

Why does Person 1 use the word `见到` and Person 2 use the word `见着`?

Is there any different meaning between using `见到` and `见着` in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Person 1 says: 我不想再见到你

> Person 2 says: 谁想再见着你

In this case, 见到 and 见着 mean the same. This use of 着 works as a ***resultative complement***. It's worth to mention that 着 should be pronounced as ***zháo***. E.g. 猜着了, 找着了, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No difference, 到 is more formal, 着 is less. In this use, 着 is pronounced "zháo,ㄓㄠˊ". However, it can be pronounced another way, and the meaning changes.

谁想看着(zháo,ㄓㄠˊ)你 - Who wants to see you.

谁想看着(zhe,ㄓㄜ)你 - Who wants look at you? Or, who wants to keep an eye on you?

Example sentences:

鑰匙找不着(ㄓㄠˊ)了 = 鑰匙找不到了.

看着(ㄓㄜ)他,別讓他跑了 - Keep an eye on him, don't let him run away.

Have fun:)

**ADD -** Another fun to note/know about the tone of "着":

着(ㄓㄠˊ)火了 (2-3-4) or (2-3-5)

着(ㄓㄠ)急了 (1-2-4) or (2-3-5)

Comment: Hi, did you mean "zháo" (阳平) as in 找不着 (zhǎobuzháo)?

Comment: 着 in 找不着 (can't find) functions differently from the  着 in 在找着 (is looking for)

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi 找不着 (3-4-2).

Comment: @TangHo This is a difficult word to explain.

Comment: It should be pronounced as zháo in 谁想再见着你, not "zhāo".

Comment: @dan 见着你 (4-2-3). I am not very good at pin-yin, and on-screen, I couldn't distinguish the difference you have provided.

Comment: Hi, sorry, a couple more suggestions. 1) **Taiwan pronunciation** of 着(zhāo)急了 differs from Putonghua 着(zháo)急了. Do you want to indicate it? 2) The **tone of 了** in 着火了(le) and 着急了(le) is neutral. You may want to indicate it as number 5 (instead of 4).

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi 1) Could be, but no intention to add. 2)  I agree. correction made. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

见到你，到 means "reach". My eyesight reaches you.

见着（zháo）你，着 means "touch". My eyesight touches you.
Related words are like 着落，着地，着凉

These two words are basically the same meaning. My feeling as a northerner is 见着 is more oral and informal. 见到 in the oral language is also fine so they mean the same in your example.